# How to interpolate handlebars values into a Rails link_to helper?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js

I'm working on a handlebars.erb template, but I'm getting an error when trying to put a handlebars `{{id}}` into a link_to helper. Any ideas how to do it?

```
<%= link_to "Link", edit_user_photo_path(id: {{id}} ) %>
```

This wont work, the value for the id will be {{id}}. If I put {{id}} outside the helper, its value is `139`. I don't know how can I make a link_to interpret the handlebars value!

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't the id be in quotes  so it's interpreted as a string?  Or is that just a typo... `id: "{{id}}"`

Comment: No because if not handlebars will not compile id...

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, you're generating a template with ERB which will **later** be run through handlebars.  If that's the case, handlebars has nothing to do with this initial render; your goal is just to get the `{{id}}` inserted in the correct place in the link.  Passing `"{{id}}"` to the url helper will certainly do that, outputting something like `"/user/photos/{{id}}/edit"`.  Now later on when you run that through handlebars, passing in the `id`, it certainly would render the URL properly.

Answer (score 1):

Since Handlebars is run on the client side of your page, it is unlikely that you will be able to use a value from Handlebars in a link that you are setting up with your Ruby code, which is evaluated by the server.

You shouldn't need Handlebars to make this link. Try to get the relevant id with your Ruby code.

Comment: The thing is I don't have the @pin.id because it's not yet created, since it compiles in the frontend. So if I inspect pin.id it will give "nil", while if I do {{id}}, it will show me the compiled id (139).

Comment: In that case, can you use the <a> tag and accomplish it with HTML?

Comment: No because it's dynamic, and I need to pass parameters to it :(

Comment: Is it posible to transform this to an <a> tag ? 

 <%= link_to "<i class='icon-write'></i>".html_safe, edit_user_photo_pin_path(user_id: user.id, photo_id: photo.id, id: {{id}} ) %></li>

Comment: For GET parameters, you can tack `?user_id={{user.id}}&photo_id={{photo.id}}` to the end of the address.

Comment: But I can get photo.id and @user.id from ruby, just pin is compiling. So I guess something like this...

<a href="/users/<%= user.id %>/photos/<%= photo.id %>/pins/{{id}}/edit">Link</a>

Comment: The same URL would have been generated by passing `"{{id}}"` into the rails url helper, unless I'm wildly missing what you're doing here.